# counting inversions with merge sort gives a negative number if the array length is 100000

Tags: c++, mergesort

I am still a beginner at programming and i am taking an online course (algorithms)

one of the practice questions was to count the number of inversions in a file containing 100000 numbers randomly ordered. I have tried this code on small data sets and it worked fine but when passing the actual data set it gives inversion count in negative number. Tried various solutions from different platforms but still couldn't resolve it yet.

so this is my code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>;
#include <conio.h>:
#include <fstream> 

using namespace std;

long merge(int a[], int start, int mid, int end) 
    int i = start; 
    int j = mid + 1; 
    int k = start; 
    int inversion=0;
    int temp[100000];

    while (i <= mid && j <= end)
    {
        if (a[i] < a[j])  
        {
            temp[k++] = a[i++]; 
        }
        else 
        {
            temp[k++] = a[j++]; 
            inversion =inversion + (mid - i);
        }
    }
    while (i <= mid) 
    {
        temp[k++] = a[i++]; 
    }
    while (j <= end) 
    {
        temp[k++] = a[j++]; 
    }

    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
    {
        a[i] = temp[i]; 
    }
    return inversion;

long Msort(int a[], int start,int end)
{
    if (start >= end)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int inversion = 0;
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;

    inversion += Msort(a, start, mid);
    inversion += Msort(a, mid + 1, end); 

    inversion += merge(a, start, mid, end)
    return inversion;
}

long ReadFromFile(char FileName[], int storage[],int n)
{
    int b;
    int count=0;
    ifstream get(FileName);
    if (!get)
    {
        cout << "no file found";
    }
    while (!get.eof())
    {
        get >> storage[count];
        count++;
    }
    b = count;
    return b;
}

int main()
{
    int valuescount = 0;
    int arr[100000];
    char filename[] = { "file.txt" };
    long n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    valuescount=ReadFromFile(filename, arr,n);
    int no_Of_Inversions = Msort(arr, 0, valuescount -1);
    cout << endl << "No of inversions are" << '\t' << no_Of_Inversions <<'\t';
    cout <<endl<< "Total no of array values sorted"<< valuescount<<endl;
    system("pause");
}
`
```

Comment: So, the temp array is declared as 100000 - why would large data even be EXPECTED to work reliably? Or: what is the “actual” data-size/range for which issues develop?

Comment: the actual data set that I have to check for inversions is of size "100000" so just to make everything in place declare it with size 100000.

Comment: I would consider the possibility that `inversion` overflows. How to check this? Single step debugging cannot be the choice when only large input causes the problem. You could add debug code. E.g. insert a check for overflow: `assert(inversion <= std::numeric_limits<int>::max() - rhs);` while `rhs` is the value to add. Using `unsigned` instead of `int` could make sense as well but wouldn't actually fix the overflow issue (except that it would eliminate the U.B. caused by overflow of `int`).

Comment: What is the meaning of _inversion_? Why do you add `(mid - i)` to `inversion` it instead of a simple increment? Try to change the type of `inversion`s to `unsigned long`.

Comment: By inversion we means that i > j where i and j are values stored in an array. So when we sort the array in my case using  'merge sort' every time when i > j we count it as an inversion. By adding (mid-i) we count the total inversions caused by that particular no in an array from the index value of J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code is not directly related to the input size. Rather, in an indirect way, the negative number of inversions you find is the result of an overflow in the variable `inversion` of the function `merge`.

Consider the case for your input size `N = 100000`. If this array of numbers is sorted in decreasing order, then all the ordered pairs in that array will be an inversion. In other words, there will be `N * (N-1) / 2` inversions to be counted. As you may have noticed, that value is slightly higher than the bounds of `unsigned int` type. Consequently, when you try and count this value in a variable of type int, overflow occurs, leading to a negative result.

To remedy this issue, you should change the type of the variable `inversion` from `int` to `long long`, in functions `merge` and `Msort`. (You should also update the return type of the functions `merge` and `Msort`) Naturally, you should assign the return value of the `Msort` call in the `main` function to a variable of type `long long` as well. In other words, change the type of variable `no_Of_Inversions` into a long long as well.

Comment: @Shamaz My bad. You should also update the type of the variable `inversion` in `Msort` function, as well as the return value of that function.

Comment: Thanks, It worked your point is valid with that it also required to change the data type of variable "no_Of_Inversions" which store the return value of the function "Msort" in main function and then display the inversion count in output statement.

Comment: @Shamaz Exactly! Unless you change the type of `no_Of_Inversions` variable, a similar overflow occurs when assigning the return value of `Msort` call in `main()` to `no_Of_Inversions`.

Comment: I'm stuck with the answer when I test the modified code on the actual data set it gives wrong answer then what it is supposed to be Can you help me figure out the problem?

Comment: @Shamaz This question is about the negative value issue, which my answer solves. Without any extra information, solving an unclear issue with your code is too general a scope for an ideal StackOverflow question. Having said that ir should be a separate and clearer question with more information, one thing you may want to check is whether `valuescount` variable stores the correct value in all cases.